# Problema de carga de un Select dentro del SweetAlert

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert2

Tengo un problema al cargar un Select desde el back, alguien me puede ayudar? La info si llega desde el back al front end solo que no se carga al control.

function cuentaAdd() {

```
console.log(0);
mostrarOverlay();
mostrarFormularioCuenta();
```

}

function mostrarFormularioCuenta() {

```
Swal.fire({
    title: 'Agregar Cuenta',
    html: `
        <input type="hidden" id="hdn_cuentaId" name="hdn_cuentaId" value="0" />
        <input id="nombre_cuenta" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Nombre" />
        <input id="numero_cuenta" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Número" />
        <select id="tipo" name="tipo" class="swal2-select">
            <option value="0">Seleccione Tipo</option>
            <option value="1">Recolectora</option>
            <option value="2">Efectivo</option>
            <option value="3">Proveedor</option>
        </select>
        <select id="id_banco" name="id_banco" class="swal2-select"></select>
        <input type="hidden" id="hdfid_banco" name="hdfid_banco" value="0" />
        <select id="id_moneda" name="id_moneda" class="swal2-select"></select>
        <input type="hidden" id="hfid_moneda" name="hfid_moneda" value="0" />
    `,
    focusConfirm: true,
    showCancelButton: true,
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
    confirmButtonColor: '#428bca',
    confirmButtonText: "Aceptar",
    allowOutsideClick: false,
    didOpen: () => {
        console.log(1);
        cargar_bancos().then(() => {
            return cargar_monedas();  
        }).then(() => {
            ocultarOverlay();  
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error("Error al cargar los datos: ", error);
            ocultarOverlay(); 
        });
    },
    preConfirm: () => {
    const nombre_cuenta = document.getElementById('nombre_cuenta').value;
    const numero_cuenta = document.getElementById('numero_cuenta').value;
    const tipo = document.getElementById('tipo').value;
    const id_banco = document.getElementById('id_banco').value;
    const id_moneda = document.getElementById('id_moneda').value;

    if (!nombre_cuenta) {
      Swal.showValidationMessage("Mira!!, Debes colocar algún nombre");
      return false;
    }
    if (!numero_cuenta) {
      Swal.showValidationMessage("Mira!!, Debes colocar algún número");
      return false;
    }
    if (tipo == 0) {
      Swal.showValidationMessage("Mira!!, Debes definir un tipo");
      return false;
    }
    if (id_banco == 0) {
      Swal.showValidationMessage("Mira , Debes seleccionar un banco");
      return false;
    }
    if (id_moneda == 0) {
      Swal.showValidationMessage("Mira , Debes seleccionar una moneda");
      return false;
    }

    return {
      nombre_cuenta,
      numero_cuenta,
      tipo,
      id_banco,
      id_moneda
    };
  }
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {        
    SaveContact();
  } else if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel) {
        cuentaLoad();
    }
});
```

};

function cargar_bancos() {

```
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $("#id_moneda").empty();
    
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "frm_mayoristas.aspx?fn=bancos",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
            $.each(response.aaData, function (i, item) {
                $("#id_banco").append(new Option(item.des, item.id));                    
            });
            console.log(2);
            resolve(); 
        },
        error: function () {
            reject(new Error('Error en la función cargar_bancos()'));
        }
    });
});
```

}
function cargar_monedas() {

```
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $("#id_moneda").empty();
    
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "frm_mayoristas.aspx?fn=monedas",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
            $.each(response.aaData, function (i, item) {
                $("#id_moneda").append(new Option(item.des, item.id));                    
            });
            console.log(3);
            resolve();
        },
        error: function () {
            reject(new Error('Error en la función cargar_monedas()'));
        }
    });
});
```

}

El orden de ejecución de las funciones en la consola indica que cargar_bancos() se ejecuta antes de que cargar_monedas() empiece y cargar_monedas() parece no ser llamada en el momento adecuado, ya que debería llamarse después de que cargar_bancos() se resuelva completamente. Además, el llamado a ocultarOverlay() se hace inmediatamente después de mostrarFormularioCuenta(), lo cual podría ocurrir antes de que los datos hayan terminado de cargar.

El orden de las operaciones debería ser el siguiente y se cumple:
Mostrar el overlay de carga (mostrarOverlay()).
Abrir el SweetAlert (mostrarFormularioCuenta()).
Dentro del didOpen del SweetAlert, cargar bancos y monedas.
Después de cargar los datos, ocultar el overlay de carga (ocultarOverlay()).